Duda y Problema con Sockets C#
estoy diseñando un app cliente-servidor en c#.
Los pongo en contexto para que puedan entender.
Necesito que el socket-servidor intente aceptar por un determinado tiempo una conexión, para eso estoy usando IAsyncResult con su AsyncWaitHandle y sú método WaitOne().
public bool Aceptar() {
   try {
      IAsyncResult ar = s.BeginAccept(null, null);
      if (ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000)) {
         s = s.EndAccept(ar);
         return true;
      }else {
         return false;
      }
   } catch {
      return false;
   }
}

Necesito este timeout porque si este método devuelve false llegará al bucle while preguntando si el servidor necesita detenerse y terminar la ejecución del servidor.
El problema que tengo es que a veces no acepta del todo al cliente o no se ejecuta una conexión válida.
Hace tiempo intente usando Poll() pero he leído ahora que en algunos escenarios aunque el socket tenga datos por leer devuelve igualmente false.
Lo que necesito saber es como abordar esta problematica.
Es decir, intentar una accept por tiempo determinado y que funcione correctamente al aceptar el cliente.
¿Cómo lo harían ustedes?
Agrego:
Este es el cliente
public bool Conectar(string ip, int port) {
   try {
      IAsyncResult result = s.BeginConnect(ip, port, null, s);
      if (!result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000)) return false;

      s.EndConnect(result);
      return true;
   } catch {
      return false;
   }
}

El cliente si pasa mi condicional, es decir, este método devuelve true, envía los datos (no tengo error de envío), pero en el servidor no hay respuesta, el socket no termina de aceptar al cliente, el método Aceptar() me devuelve false.

"El problema que tengo es que a veces no acepta del todo al cliente o no se ejecuta una conexión válida." si pasa esto, no hay conexion.. no entiendo que esperas que pase...

Yo probe tu código y me funciona. Lo mejor es que agregues un [MCVE] tanto del cliente como del servidor para reproducir el problema que estas experimentando

Tengo un cliente que usa beginconnect, con la misma logica del accept, uso waithandle para el timeout, el método me devuelve true, supongo que se ha conectado, pero en el servidor no hay respuesta. @gbianchi

He editado el cuerpo de está publicación, en ella detallo el método que utilizo para conectarme.

perdon.. pero estas usando esto??? public IAsyncResult BeginAccept (AsyncCallback? callback, object? state);... si es asi.. que esperas que pase si no le dijiste que hacer cuando conecte ni tenes el objeto de conexion... o me estoy perdiendo algo???

Me parece que está haciendo al como un PING, el problema es que no le conecta, para eso no es necesario el callback

Yo te insisto que agregues un [MCVE] que reproduzca tu error, lo que tú has agregado es código suelto que es irreproducible. Tanto, que yo al completar tu código me ha funcionado de maravillas, si el cliente conecta antes de 5s se acepta y canso contrario no, y lo habré probado unas 20 veces
